# Illegal nesting in Haml

Tags: haml

Here's my Haml code:

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    %table {'width' => 638, 'border' => 0, 'cellpadding' => 0, 'cellspacing' => 0}
      %tr
        %td {'width' => 27, 'height' => 100}
        %td {'width' => 582, 'height' => 100}
        %td {'width' => 29, 'height' => 100}
```

when I enter `haml example.haml example.html`, I get the following error:

`Syntax error on line 5: Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %table and nested within it.`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces between the tags and the braces, like so:

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    %table{'width' => 638, 'border' => 0, 'cellpadding' => 0, 'cellspacing' => 0}
      %tr
        %td{'width' => 27, 'height' => 100}
        %td{'width' => 582, 'height' => 100}
        %td{'width' => 29, 'height' => 100}
```

Comment: Also, note that if you're doing vanilla attributes you can ease your typing burden by using [HTML-style attributes](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#htmlstyle_attributes_), e.g. `%td(width=27 height=100)`; that's four fewer characters per attribute! :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to help others avoid the illegal nesting situation if they don't realize they made a typo like me.

**It will say illegal nesting if you forget the % in an element**

```
p.small
  Some text!! Wow!!!!!!
```

That will result in the illegal nesting error. Don't forget your %s!

```
%p.small
  Some text that will actually view without errors, Profit!
```